# Add variable to an array when button is pressed

Tags: arrays

I have this inside a mapping in a table and right now when the button is pressed, the setLocId has the id from the pressed loc. (loc is a table with locations)

```
const [locId,setLocId]= useState([]);
(loc: any) => (<div>
                  <Button
                    className="secondary"
                    name="Add to your itinerary"
                    onClick={() => {
                      setLocId(loc._id);
                    }}
                  /></div>
                ),
```

I want that, when I press a button, the loc._id to go to an array of all pressed id's.